# Cast directshow custom filter to IBaseFilter failed on .NET 4.0

Tags: c#, directshow, directshow.net

I am a beginner in Directshow.NET. To develop an application which will record desktop screen,I have downloaded an project from [this link](http://web2.codeproject.com/Articles/421167/Pure-NET-DirectShow-Filters-in-Csharp).

Virtual cam is registered through `regasm` and working in `graphstudio`, C# code using line of code:

```
  Type type = Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(new Guid("F90CF082-213F-4F17-8B19-68267C72052F"));
  IBaseFilter screenRecorderFilter = (IBaseFilter)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

These projects are developed on .NET framework 2.0 so changed framework version to 4.0 (Client profile). project build was successful, assemble got registered using `regasm` and checked filter in `graphstudio` and found working fine. If I execute C# project where we have used this filter it's giving exception as

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'DesktopVirtualCamFilters.VirtualCamFilter' to type
>   'DirectShowLib.IBaseFilter'.

looks like casting at line `IBaseFilter screenRecorderFilter = (IBaseFilter)Activator.CreateInstance(type);` is getting failed.

Why casting is getting failed if framework version 4.0 is selected, even if filter successfully working in `graphstudio`. what changes are required to work with 4.0

For code reference I have uploaded project on [this link](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=49095110196575451950)

Class declaration:

```
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [Guid("F90CF082-213F-4F17-8B19-68267C72052F")]
    [AMovieSetup(Merit.Normal,AMovieSetup.CLSID_VideoInputDeviceCategory)]
    public class VirtualCamFilter : BaseSourceFilter, IAMFilterMiscFlags
    {

    }
```

Comment: Show the `DesktopVirtualCamFilters.VirtualCamFilter` class declaration.

Comment: @ZverevEugene updated in question.